Error when training my model : Cannot take the length of shape with unknown rank
When running :
class FaceTracker(Model): 
    def init(self, eyetracker,  **kwargs): super().init(**kwargs) self.model = eyetracker
    
    def compile(self, opt, classloss, localizationloss, **kwargs):
        super().compile(**kwargs)
        self.closs = classloss
        self.lloss = localizationloss
        self.opt = opt
    
    def train_step(self, batch, **kwargs):
        X, y = batch
        
        # Assurez-vous que X a la forme correcte (batch_size, 120, 120, 3)
        print(f"X shape: {X.shape}")  # Devrait être (batch_size, 120, 120, 3)
        
        # Diviser y en classes et coordonnées
        classes = y[0]  # Extraire la classe, forme (batch_size, 1)
        coords = y[1]   # Extraire les coordonnées, forme (batch_size, 4)
        
        # Assurez-vous que les types sont corrects
        classes = tf.cast(classes, tf.float32)  # Convertir en float si nécessaire
        coords = tf.cast(coords, tf.float32)    # Convertir en float
        
        # Afficher les formes de classes et de coordonnées
        print(f"classes shape: {classes.shape}")  # Devrait être (batch_size, 1)
        print(f"coords shape: {coords.shape}")    # Devrait être (batch_size, 4)
    
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            # Sortie du modèle : classes prédites et coordonnées prédites
            predicted_classes, predicted_coords = self.model(X, training=True)
            
            # Afficher les formes des prédictions
            print(f"predicted_classes shape: {predicted_classes.shape}")  # Devrait être (batch_size, 1)
            print(f"predicted_coords shape: {predicted_coords.shape}")    # Devrait être (batch_size, 4)
    
            # Calcul des pertes
            batch_classloss = self.closs(classes, predicted_classes)  # classes, predicted_classes
            batch_localizationloss = self.lloss(coords, predicted_coords)  # coords, predicted_coords
            
            # Perte totale
            total_loss = batch_localizationloss + 0.5 * batch_classloss
    
            # Calcul des gradients
            grads = tape.gradient(total_loss, self.model.trainable_variables)
        
        # Appliquer les gradients
        self.opt.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.model.trainable_variables))
        
        # Retourner les informations de perte
        return {"total_loss": total_loss, "class_loss": batch_classloss, "regress_loss": batch_localizationloss}
    
    
    def test_step(self, batch, **kwargs): 
        X, y = batch
        
        classes, coords = self.model(X, training=False)
        
        batch_classloss = self.closs(y[0], classes)
        batch_localizationloss = self.lloss(tf.cast(y[1], tf.float32), coords)
        total_loss = batch_localizationloss+0.5*batch_classloss
        
        return {"total_loss":total_loss, "class_loss":batch_classloss, "regress_loss":batch_localizationloss}
        
    def call(self, X, **kwargs): 
        return self.model(X, **kwargs)

and following :
model = FaceTracker(facetracker)
model.compile(opt, classloss, regressloss)

and therein lies the problem:
logdir='logs' 

tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=logdir) 

hist = model.fit(train, epochs=10, validation_data=val, callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])

It prints :
ValueError                                
Traceback (most recent call last) Cell In[285], line 3       
1 logdir='logs'       
2 tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=logdir) 
----> 3 hist = model.fit(train, epochs=10, validation_data=val, callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])  File C:\Louis\TIPEEEE\.venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py:122, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)     119     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)     120     # To get the full stack trace, call:     121     # `keras.config.disable_traceback_filtering()` --> 122     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None     123 finally:     124     del filtered_tb  Cell In[283], line 39, in FaceTracker.train_step(self, batch, **kwargs)      36 print(f"predicted_coords shape: {predicted_coords.shape}")    # Devrait être (batch_size, 4)      38 # Calcul des pertes ---> 39 batch_classloss = self.closs(classes, predicted_classes)  # classes, predicted_classes      40 batch_localizationloss = self.lloss(coords, predicted_coords)  # coords, predicted_coords      42 # Perte totale  ValueError: Cannot take the length of shape with unknown rank.

I have no idea how to solve the problem, I've looked at problems I've encountered before, but I can't find a solution to my problem.
Thank you for your help

The error suggests that the rank of either predicted_classes, predicted_coords, classes, or coords is unknown at runtime. Maybe the model isn't returning tensors with the expected shapes.Print the exact shapes of both the model outputs (predicted_classes, predicted_coords) and the ground truth labels (classes, coords):


print(f"Classes shape (y[0]): {classes.shape}")
print(f"Coords shape (y[1]): {coords.shape}")
print(f"Predicted classes shape: {predicted_classes.shape}")
print(f"Predicted coords shape: {predicted_coords.shape}")



predicted_classes and classes must have the same shape. predicted_coords and coords should have the same shape too. If you need more info regarding the types of python variables in Tensorflow, you can see here: https://www.theengineeringprojects.com/2023/01/types-of-python-variables-in-tensorflow.html
